# Classic ASP and ASP.NET sites on the same IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I have to set two web sites on the same IIS 7.5.

One of them is Classic ASP with MSAccess Database. The other one is ASP.NET. Meaning they will use different Application Pools.

I only have one port open : 80.

How can this be configured?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure host headers ("Bindings") in IIS for your first site before you can open the second. In other words you have to tell IIS which hostname leads to the first website, cause you can't run 2 websites as "default" hostname.

Comment: whenever I try to open the second site I get a message from IIS that port 80 is already taken

Comment: What if I can only have one http address, like www.mysite.com

and I want the asp site to be in www.mysite.com/asp

and the asp.net in www.mysite.com/aspnet ?

Host headers don't allow this.

Comment: Then you don't need 2 websites. You could do it with a virtual directory or an application, or simply put all your asp pages in an "asp" subfolder into your main website containing aspx pages (not necessarily in a subfolder)

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. I keep getting 403 error.

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 applications under the same website using the same port (80).
Each one can have different Application Pool.

This way, to browse applications, you will type

```
http://mywebsite/app1
http://mywebsite/app2
```

---

Otherwise you can have 2 different websites using the same port, but this involves [configuring host header bindings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) over IIS and creating  [C-NAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) in your DNS

This way, to browse applications, you will type

```
http://app1.mydomain.com
http://app2.mydomain.com
```